# Causal bandpass using fft?

Tags: fft, bandpass, causality

I would like to take a time series of several spikes or narrow Gaussians and bandpass using an ift/ifft together with a frequency domain mask to create a series containing band-limited spikes. This is pretty simple but I have an additional desire - that the resulting band-limited spikes are causal - that is each band limited spike has a sharp onset (at the position of the original spike) followed by a tail dependent on the bandpass parameters.

The ultimate goal is a series that looks superficially like a superposition of a multitude of earthquakes.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks very much for any guidance.

Comment: Why do you want to use FFT and not an ordinary IIR bandpass filter? IIR is always causal and much cheaper to implement.

Comment: I am certainly open to that but I am not well educated in signal processing although I do have a little experience with ffts. Can you point to a simple reference?

Comment: OK, inspired by the comment above, I looked around a bit and I came across the implementations of constructing and applying a filter, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740348/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-signal-in-python   I ended up using lfilter rather than filtfilt (which is zero phase).